# how to give the date format option in json?

Tags: javascript, php, json

In my php script am using the json to pass parameters here. While passing parameters, if i pass date as `"09-09-2015"`..it works, but if I pass the date as `$date` it doesn't work.

what can I do to fix this?

```
$item1="test";
$item2="testname";
$date = date("d-m-Y");
```

i given the following json format,it can't take the date.

```
$json='{"item":'.$item1.',"itemname":'.$item2.',"date":'.$date.'}';
```

but the following one is works.

```
$json='{"item":'.$item1.',"itemname":'.$item2.',"date":"09-09-2015"}';
```

How can I solve this issue?

**actual code:**

**working**:

```
$json='{
"itemNo": "ITM001",
"custmrCode": "289",
"date":"10-09-2015",
"orderList":
[{
"productId": 1000014,
"qty": 2,
"price": 10
}]
}';
$data = json_decode($json);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

**Not working:**

```
$json='{
    "itemNo": "ITM001",
    "custmrCode": "289",
    "date":'."$date".',
    "orderList":
    [{
    "productId": 1000014,
    "qty": 2,
    "price": 10
    }]
    }';
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Check $date variable and there may issue of single or double quotes in $json while adding $date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json='{"item":'.$item1.',"itemname":'.$item2.',"date":"'.$date.'"}';
```

it's working

Answer (score 2):

You can make that store that in array variable then encode to json.

```
$item1="test";
$item2="testname";
$date = date("d-m-Y");

$json = json_encode(['item' => $item1, 'item2' => $item2, 'date' => $date]);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array then simply encode it in json

```
$arr = array();

$item1="test";
$item2="testname";
$date = date("d-m-Y");

$arr['item'] = $item1;
$arr['itemname'] = $item2;
$arr['date'] = $date;

echo $output = json_encode($arr);  //this will encode arr to json
```